# How do I get the second to last achievement?

Tags: achievements, bug-defense

I've unlocked all the trophies in [Bug Defense](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobl7.bugd&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tb2JsNy5idWdkIl0.) for Android except for the penultimate one.  Has anyone unlocked the second to last trophy, and if so, how do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second to last trophy is awarded for killing the baby mantis in Level 1-4.

I don't see how you got all the trophies without getting that trophy, because you have to kill the mantis to get perfect on level 1-4!

Are you *sure* you have all the trophies?

Comment: you're right, i was missing the perfect for 1-4 as well...doh